# better way to configure the email address with rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently, I'm working on the application which is developed in rails 3* and ruby 1.9.3. I have configured some email address in the initializers section as YML file for each environments.

But, the requirement is keep on changing (but it'll happened every month 1 or 2 times) that need to add/remove the email address from the configuration. Hence, I need to restart the server on every changes. Because, I configured those address in the initializers.

Is there any better way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the email without re-deploying / restarting the server, you can always create a `Email` model and persist it to the database. By adding a `current` field / column (boolean value) and a scope `scope :current, -> { where(current: true) }` you can access the email via `Email.current.first.address`, for instance. You might need to ensure that one and only one 'current' Email object ist present at any given time.

**edit**

1. creating a model does not mean you have to create UI for it. Just use the console to change the email if you have to.
2. the configuration and models are loaded at startup, and if you don't want to do any reloading in production, which is slow and not recommended, you have to use the DB for persistence.
3. if you really want to go down the "reload" route, set `config.cache_classes = true` in `config/environments/production.rb` and specify the email in a constant outside the config directory (in some model or controller) like this `EMAIL = 'whatever@email.com'`. You would have to change the production code on each production machine, without a server restart. Sounds very hacky. Look into zero-downtime deploys à la [Github](https://github.com/blog/517-unicorn) for a more elegant solution. Redeploying should be cheap and painless.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But, this is not what I'm looking for. I don't like to create any model and UI part for this. Anyway I'll update my question.